# Let's get critical: Aug 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Salesforce Stack Exchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Using the Summer 2013 Metadata API (v28.0) as a Web Reference in Visual Studio](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12869/using-the-summer-2013-metadata-api-v28-0-as-a-web-reference-in-visual-studio)

  **Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Sending nulls in JS remoting](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12903/sending-nulls-in-js-remoting)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Changing sender email display name on force.com sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13126/changing-sender-email-display-name-on-force-com-sites)

  **Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 13, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [how to control API access to applications](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12880/how-to-control-api-access-to-applications)

  **Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Inconsistent behavior for login with Customer Portal and Sites](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12930/inconsistent-behavior-for-login-with-customer-portal-and-sites)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Lead assignment rule in a trigger](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13651/lead-assignment-rule-in-a-trigger)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Using a component to add attachments to visualforce email template and showing email link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12899/using-a-component-to-add-attachments-to-visualforce-email-template-and-showing-e)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Calling too many getters](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12953/calling-too-many-getters)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [Connecting several third party app accounts to a single Sales force account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/connecting-several-third-party-app-accounts-to-a-single-sales-force-account)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Passing Paramaters from a future class to another class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/passing-paramaters-from-a-future-class-to-another-class)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

Answer (score 2):

This site has been amazing to browse and see the solutions and the possibility of getting answered is huge .

I think there are many duplicates that should be examined and closed .

One thing that's really needed is formatting and look and feel of site and some publicity on the existence of this site .Many salesforce developers dont even know this site exists and thats the biggest challenge .